# Can't get data from Dark Sky API

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I try to get information about the weather hourly from the Dark Sky API, but the code stops working at the if let data = hourly["data"] as? [String : AnyObject] line (checked with printing stuff after every line). I want to know what is wrong with my code. I think it could be something with the "data" let, but I don't know for sure.

```
 let Task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequestDark) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                if let hourly = json["hourly"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    if let data = hourly["data"] as? [String : AnyObject]{


                        if let hourNum = data["14"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            if let chanceRain = hourNum["precipProbability"] as? Float{
                                self.chanceHour1 = String(chanceRain)
                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                                self.ChanceRainLabel.text = self.chanceHour1
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    Task2.resume() test
```

The strange part is, this does work:

```
let urlRequestDark = URLRequest(url: URL (string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/(API Key)/(coordinates)")!)

    let Task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequestDark) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]


                if let currently = json["currently"] as? [String : AnyObject] {

                    if let chance2 = currently["precipProbability"] as? Float{
                        print(String(chance2))
                        self.chance = String(Int(chance2 * 100)) + "%"
                        self.PreType = currently["precipType"] as? String
                    }

                        if let _ = json["error"]{
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                        self.TypeLabel.text = self.PreType
                        self.ChanceLabel.text = self.chance
                    }
                }


            }catch let jsonError{
                print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    Task.resume()
```

Comment: @Check you Request Url i think you are missing with url

Comment: I am using the same urlrequest for both examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made couple mistakes.

First, `"data"` is an array of dictionaries, so it should be cast to [[String : AnyObject]].

Second, you're trying to subscript array by String, not Int.

Third, using `self` in escaping closures potentially creates retain cycles.

Let me propose you some fixed and adjusted code.

```
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequestDark) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject],
            let hourly = json["hourly"] as? [String : AnyObject],
            let data = hourly["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]],
            data.count > 14,
            let chanceRain = data[14]["precipProbability"] as? Float {
                self?.chanceHour1 = String(chanceRain)
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    self?.ChanceRainLabel.text = self?.chanceHour1
                }
        }
    } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task2.resume()
```

Comment: I want you to know that I love you! IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import UIKit

class WebService: NSObject {

    var session = URLSession()

    public class var sharedInstance: WebService {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = WebService()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    override init() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    }


 public func weatherData(coordinate:String,APIkey:String,completion:@escaping (_ responsedata:NSDictionary?,_ error:NSError?) -> Void) {

            var Baseurl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/\(APIkey)/\(coordinate)"
            Baseurl = Baseurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            let weatherRequestUrl = URL(string: Baseurl)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: weatherRequestUrl!)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

                guard error == nil && data != nil else {

                    return
                }
                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                    if httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {

                        print("Something is wrong")
                    }
                }
                do {
                    let WindlocationData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

                    print(WindlocationData)
                    completion(WindlocationData,nil)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {

                    completion(nil,error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        }
}
```

And call API like this!

func callAPI(latlong:String,APIkeyParm:String) {

```
WebService.sharedInstance.weatherData(coordinate: latlong,APIkey: APIkeyParm) { (responsData, error) in

    if error == nil{

        print("Response data is-\(responsData)")
    }
}
```

}

Call the method like this

```
let latlongStr = "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
self.callAPI(latlong: latlongStr,APIkeyParm: "APIKeyString")
```

**One importent thing you need to pass latlong like this format 23.022504999999999,72.571362100000002**